# Best way to save game in story game

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structure, savegame

In a while I plan to create a story game that would have different routes and endings and I was wondering what would be the best way to save a game of a game like this, if it would be a folder, individual file. Etc.

Comment: What makes you think that you couldn't get away with a single file containing a list of flags of whether they've taken a route? You'd get better answers from us if you tried something first and asked about issues you encountered doing that, as we'd be able to provide help in an actual context.

Comment: This does not look like a problem that needs any particular optimization. You could do the most blunt, naive thing, and it would probably work just fine if all you need to save/restore is the user's current place in the story/flags about choices they made along the way.

Comment: "Maybe the real save file was the choices we made along the way." -- DMGregory, paraphrased.

Answer (score 1):

The information you need to save is:

1. Which step of the story is the player currently on?
2. What's the state of the game? (variable values, story flags etc.)

This should not be a lot of data, so saving those to a file should be sufficient.